# Metric of vector bundle of Riemann manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Whether there is a standard metric of vector bundle of Riemann manifold?

How is it defined ?

Using the exponent map ? Or just using the metric of $\mathbb R^n$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no standard metric on the tangent bundle of a Riemannian manifold. You may want, though, to take a look at the Sasaki metric and at the Cheeger-Gromoll metric, both of which are presented in [this master's thesis](http://www.matematik.lu.se/matematiklu/personal/sigma/students/Elias-Kappos-MSc.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The Levi-Civita connection lets you choose a *horizontal* space in the tangent bundle of $TM$. The metric in the horizontal direction is then induced from the metric on $M$ itself, and the metric in the vertical direction stems from a canonical identification of the complementary vertical space with the fiber $T_p M$.

Comment: Isn't this the Sasaki metric? I wouldn't call it standard, maybe it is the simplest one, but why not choose Cheeger's metric instead? No, there is no standard metric on the tangent bundle of a Riemannian manifold.

Comment: @AlexM. you can try to clarify what your objectives are. The metric via a choice of a horizontal space is certainly a natural one, and Sasaki was at least a few decades before Cheeger, both of whom are great mathematicians :-)